# Trigger function when element from template is added to page using jQuery and Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, templates, backbone.js

I write Backbone View that load Google Maps API like this.

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'media-frame hide-menu hide-router',

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },

        render: function(){
            this.$el.html($("#map-editor").html());
            this.loadMap();
        },

        loadMap: function() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
                zoom: 13
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (place.geometry) {
                    map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(15);
                } 
            });
        }
});
```

Google Maps needs to bind an element with id `map-canvas` to load. That element is in the template inside element with id `map-editor` as its container. So I just write `this.loadMap()` exactly after I call its container.

The problem is.. it throws error because element `map-editor` is called by Google Maps when it's not yet created even after it starts to create the container.

Unfortunately, I call the template container using .html() that provides no callback.

So, if there's a way it can works as it should, please tell me. I prefer no plugin if possible.

NOTE: those elements I'm talking about is inside a template on the same page (`<script type="text/template">`). So it won't be rendered before it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I can't see how you're instantiating your view, but I'm betting your $el is not yet on the page by the time the loadMap() function is called.  Try removing the className attribute from your view and move that element outside the view, and pass in a selector for the el attribute when you create your view:

```
var view = new MapView({
    el: '.media-frame.hide-menu.hide-router'
});
```

This will tell backbone to make $el this dom element that already exists in your dom.

Otherwise, even though your map-editor contents are inside $el when you call loadMap() since jquery's html() function is synchronous, $el isn't in the dom yet so thus .map-canvas isn't in the dom yet either.